# changing the class name in nested divs

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I have a nested divs as follows, how can I change the class of span in the div whose id is inside-one? 
thanks.
my code is as follows:

```
$("#top span.myclass").removeClass("myclass").addClass("myclass-new");

<div id="top">
    <div id="inside-one">
       <span id="s1" class="myclass"></span>
    </div>
<div id="inside-two">
       <span id="s2" class="myclass"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#inside-one').find('span').removeClass('myClass').addClass('myClass-new');
```

Answer (score 0):

To access from `#top` without using span ID

```
$('#top #inside-one span.myclass').toggleClass('myclass-new');
```

To access from `#inside-one` without using span ID

```
$('#inside-one span.myclass').toggleClass('myclass-new');
```

or simply use the span ID

```
$('#s1').toggleClass('myclass-new');
```

**Edit:** In case if you have many span inside `#inside-one` and want to access just the first span with `.myclass` ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/MB2Du/2/))

```
$('#top #inside-one span.myclass:first-child').toggleClass('myclass-new');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/MB2Du/1/)

Comment: thanks but I need to use "id=top" div. Is there a way to do this? I have to specify which inside-one beceuse there are two.

Comment: yes, try $('#top #inside-one span.myclass').toggleClass('myclass-new');